# m.subdomain - am I on the right track of understanding?

Tags: css, mobile, web, smartphone

I gotta a question, but not sure if I understand it right so here it goes:-)

for example take google.com

If you browse to google.com on your smartphone it navigates to m.google.com
This I understand can be done by detecting device widths etc. but does that mean that google re-wrote the page for mobile devices or can you treat the m.subdomain like a ghost type domain??

I mean, you can navigate to m.google.com but it really is just google.com with a different css or whatever - the index page is exactly the same.

I guess what I am getting at is - if I make a change in an index or any page in the main domain - will I need to update the subdomain separately if I decide to use a m.subdomain setup?

Hope it makes sense,
Cheers Jeff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this:

- m.example.com is a new and separate website that needs updating whenever you update www.example.com
- m.example.com is an alias of www.example.com. Your site at www.example.com needs to serve something different (e.g the CSS or even different template) whenever the http request is for m.example.com

Comment: This is all correct. You also want cross-size browser detection. The page code on any of these sites should have a hunt tree based on browser type. If the browser is a mobile device, redirect to m.mydomain.com; if a desktop browser, redirect to www.mydomain.com; etc.

Comment: Cool, I also just thought of a way to make it easier - if I serve the content through a database then I only need to update it in one place:-) just came to me hehe:-)

Comment: I want to know is it our job to detect mobiles and redirect to m subdomain or browsers do it automatically.

Comment: @Pooya: browsers don't do this automatically. You need some kind of script to detect mobiles based on user agent or other means. e.g http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ (this may not be the most up to date one, but it is a start)